# unpack requires a bytes object of length 32

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I need to pack the data and export to the csv file as well as read that csv file and decode the data.

this my code for pack the data

```
from struct import *

raw_data = [[76.94,76.944,76.945],[76.97,76.979,76.980],[77.025,77.025,77.025]]
for data in raw_data:
    binary_format = pack('fff',raw_data[0][0],raw_data[0][1],raw_data[0][2])
    print(binary_format)
    list_data = [binary_format]

    with open('samples.csv','a') as csvFile:
        writer=csv.writer(csvFile,delimiter=',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerows(list_data)                                                  
        csvFile.close()
```

This is for decode the data.

```
import csv
from struct import *

formater = 'fff'
with open('samples.csv', 'rb') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    for row in reader:
        print(unpack(formater,row[0].encode('UTF-8')))
csvFile.close()
```

the following error is

### struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 32

excepted output like this

```
76.94,76.944,76.945
76.97,76.979,76.980
77.025,77.025,77.025
```

Comment: `unpack` is for parsing *binary data*. You have a regular CSV - text - file, with spaces as separators.

Comment: sorry forgot to delete the extra space

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: @muthu why do you want to write it as binary?

Comment: memory usage  problem that is a reason

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of how the pack/unpack works.

`x = pack("ddd", 22, 33, 44)`

`x` in this case is `b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x006@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80@@\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00F@'`

`unpack(x)` yields `(22.0, 33.0, 44.0)`

Is the data you retrieve from the CSV a hexbinary ?

Comment: @muthu could you mark my answer as the right one if it is?

Comment: @muthu ok what's the problem?